# Insert selected checkbox value to database using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm trying to insert selected checkbox value into my database but I don't seem to know how because I'm new to laravel.

This is the foreach code:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
                                    <?php $id +=1; ?>
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <li class="list-group-item group-containers">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->name }}" onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver"
                                                        value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                                    <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                        <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-8">
                                                        <div class="">{{ $user->name }}</div>
                                                        <label for="" class="text-secondary">{{ $user->email }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                    @endforeach
```

Here is my checkbox code:

```
                        <div class="card-body scroll" style="background-color: #F2F2F2">
                            <div id="listUser"></div>
                                <ol class="list-group" style="display:none">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">
                                                    <img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-8">
                                                <div class="">{{ $users[0]->name }}</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
```

And my javascript code:

```
function checkBox(cb) {
        var inners = '<ol id="'+ cb.value +'" class="list-group">' +
            '<div class="card">' +
            '<li class="list-group-item">' +
            '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="col-1 c-avatar mr-3">' +
            '<img class="c-avatar-img" src="{{ url('/assets/img/avatars/3.png') }}">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-8">' +
            '<div class="">' + cb.value + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</li>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</ol>';
            console.log(cb.value);

        if (cb.checked == true) {
            //text.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('listUser').innerHTML += inners;
        } else {
            // text.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(cb.value).remove();
        }
    }
```

The data I'm trying to insert is the name and email. Is there any solutions?

Comment: did you receive any error message in the console?

Comment: there are no error to my current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed something

1. You are forget to add `name` attribute in your checkbox (also you have duplicate `value` attribute) `<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $user->name }}" onclick="checkBox(this)" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="approver" value="{{ $user->name }}">`
2. Your email doesn't have any checkbox

Comment: my value name is just like what you suggested. and for the email, is there any way to automatically include the email to the name checkbox without using another checkbox? like hidden type input?

Comment: Yes, you can use hidden input for it. But why you need name and email to be checked/not at the same time?

Comment: please kindly up vote or mark as accepted if you find this useful